# Change a static ID into a variable

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, shopp

I hope someone can help me, I am sure this is simple but for the life of me I cannot get it right.

```
<?php shopp('storefront','product', 'id=36' ); ?>
```

I want to make the 'id=36' a variable which is called from a custom meta box. The function I am using to call the ID number is `$my_meta['price']`

So I ended up with something like this: `<?php shopp('storefront','product', 'id=$my_meta['price']' ); ?>`Which doesn't work. When I insert this `$my_meta['price']` into a post it displays the number successfully, so that is all working.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Please and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<?php shopp('storefront','product', "id=" . $my_meta['price'] ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) with [curly braces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) if you want to expand variables within strings:

```
<?php shopp('storefront', 'product', "id={$my_meta['price']}"); ?>
```

If you wish to only use [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), you can append the variable to the string:

```
<?php shopp('storefront', 'product', 'id=' . $my_meta['price']); ?>
```

Comment: Hi mc10, thanks for answering so quickly. I have already tried that and it causes a syntax error.

Comment: @DarylGlass Try my modified version; I added curly braces around the variable.